# spark collect operation on large dataframe break EMR nodes

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I am running spark on a big dataframe (800G) on EMR(1 master+ 8 spot instances). When I do "count", the console starts to through out errors as below, and 3 out of the 8 nodes become "unhealthy" in hadoop console. The error is `1/4 local-dirs are bad: /mnt/yarn; 1/1 log-dirs are bad: /var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers`. How to avoid this error, and how to recover those broken nodes?

```
scala> df1.count
[Stage 13:===================>                                (312 + 540) / 852]20/06/16 06:38:14 WARN BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: No more replicas available for rdd_46_0 !
[Stage 13:===================>                                (314 + 538) / 852]20/06/16 06:38:14 WARN BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: No more replicas available for rdd_46_5 !
20/06/16 06:38:14 WARN BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: No more replicas available for rdd_46_4 !
20/06/16 06:38:14 WARN BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: No more replicas available for rdd_46_11 !
20/06/16 06:38:14 WARN BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: No more replicas available for rdd_46_10 !
...
[Stage 13:===================>                                (315 + 537) / 852]20/06/16 06:38:15 WARN BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: No more replicas available for rdd_46_66 !
20/06/16 06:38:15 WARN BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: No more replicas available for rdd_46_67 !
20/06/16 06:38:15 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Requesting driver to remove executor 228 for reason Container marked as failed: container_1592285107819_0001_01_000243 on host: ip-10-10-3-62.i.xxxx.com. Exit status: -100. Diagnostics: Container released on a *lost* node.
20/06/16 06:38:15 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Requesting driver to remove executor 292 for reason Container marked as failed: container_1592285107819_0001_01_000307 on host: ip-10-10-3-62.i.xxxx.com. Exit status: -100. Diagnostics: Container released on a *lost* node.
...
20/06/16 06:38:15 ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 228 on ip-10-10-3-62.i.xxxx.com: Container marked as failed: container_1592285107819_0001_01_000243 on host: ip-10-10-3-62.i.xxx.com. Exit status: -100. Diagnostics: Container released on a *lost* node.
....
```

Hadoop 
[image]

Comment: If you use spot instances, it may happen that it get taken away. In that case if your executors are running on that node those will get killed. If your application master is running on that node your job will fail. So its recommended to use CORE nodes on-demand, And use TASK node as spot. Because your application master will only get created on CORE nodes.

Comment: @Snigdhajyoti in this case the 3 instances just become unhealthy, but still listed as running and looks normal in aws console. So it is more likely they are broken due to the data size.

Comment: This happens if your nodes run out of storage as well. Add more ebs volumes to your nodes